# "3D" zoom in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, 3d

Are there any websites/tutorials that can simulate the zoom effect on [this website](http://sawyerhollenshead.com/writing/14/3d-zooming-using-css-transforms/) using **just Javascript** and **no CSS3 transitions**? I need to replicate the effect on IE7+.

Demo site here: http://labs.sawyerhollenshead.com/lab/css-3d-transform/

Alternatively, what approach/steps should one take to replicate it? What, if any, algorithms should I look into?

Comment: You haven't linked to a website that has a zoom effect. You've linked to a tutorial about how to implement one. Follow the tutorial you linked to.

Comment: @Quentin: the tutorial is for CSS3 Transitions, which I can't use. I need to replicate the style of fake 3d zoom using just javascript.

Comment: +1 Once edited, this is a legit question.

Comment: Can I play devils advocate and ask why exactly you need to support IE7 to the point where the layout and functionally is identical? Could you not show a fallback version that doesn't zoom, and perhaps just scrolls? I would argue that's a much better option, as it's likely that the amount of IE7 visitors you have is lower than any other browser and continuously falling. The amount of effort to implement something like this in IE7 could be a great effort for very little return, and actually impact the experience of your site in more popular browsers.

Comment: @amustill research has shown that a significant portion of the visitors to the current website use IE7&8, so we need to support those browsers.

Comment: @amustill providing a different interface isn't an option, and this functionality is perfectly possible on IE7. I'm just asking for advice on the maths and/or working examples I can learn from.

Comment: Deleting my previous comment was unnecessary as I'm only trying to provide constructive advice that a lot of other experienced, forward-thinking developers would subscribe to as well. I'm still convinced that replicating this functionality in older IE's will only create more problems, especially with inconsistency bugs across minor versions of IE, but here's an article that explains the maths of transforms in IE's Matrix filter - http://extremelysatisfactorytotalitarianism.com/blog/?p=1002

Answer (score 0):

With some work on your end you could try and use Zoomooz [Link here.](https://jaukia.github.io/zoomooz/)

It does not have native IE7 support, but if your smart you might be able to mess with the code, and get it to work.
Asking IE7 an ancient browser to do things invented after it was created it kind of stretch. But if you want it bad enough...